# Make function shorter in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to do away with variable x in this function?:

```
numocc x = map (length.filter(==x))
```

For example if I have this function:

```
numocc x l = map (countt x) l
```

I can to do away with variable l and get this:

```
numocc x = map (countt x)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "pointfree" program to answer questions like this

```
> pointfree "numocc x = map (length . filter (==x))"

numocc = map . (length .) . filter . (==)
```

---

edit

here it is in action

```
> let numocc x = map (length . filter (==x))
> let numocc' = map . (length .) . filter . (==)

numocc 'a' ["aa", "bb"] --outputs [2, 0]
numocc' 'a' ["aa", "bb"] --also outputs [2, 0]
```

Basically, it counts the number of param1's are in each element in the list items of param2

```
numocc 'a' ["aa", "bba"] --outputs [2, 1]
numocc' 'a' ["aa", "bba"] --also outputs [2, 1]
```

Comment: In fact it's a good program but results of "pointfree" - numocc = map . (length .) . filter . (==)  doesn't work.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @KoinArab- I just compared the function you gave to the one pointfree gives for a few values, and it checks for me....  Can you give an example where the two differ?  The function basically counts the number of param1's in the lists of lists in param2.

Comment: The only difference I can spot is that the pointfree version actually builds `(x==)` instead of `(==x)`, but this is irrelevant.

Comment: I think the problem was that I was using WinHugs instead ghc. Now it's ok. Thanks :)